# BizTalk Flat File Schema Wizard empty field issue

Tags: xsd, biztalk, flat-file

I have a repeating record that looks like this:

```
12345               joe, smith            123 main st            apt 12      65
14345               jane, doe             323 south st           1st fl      44
12745               bob, adams            623 high rd                        33
```

How do I configure the wizard to deal with records like Bob, that have address2 field blank.
Is there even a way to do this in the FFSW?
Note that these columns are not tab delimited, so I can only use "Relative Position"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your records are fixed length there should be no problem doing this using the flat file wizard.  You can specify field lengths.  follow the wizard as detailed below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Monster. For some reason this exact setup failed for me until I inserted a dummy value for all records that were lacking an address2.  I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Turns out that the problem was the footer record that had a trailing <cr>.  In addition, there was some fudgy format problem with the file that seems to go away after it is saved in wordpad.  But I think the solution can be found here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/655d2972-724f-416b-a924-02c9b27d38aa/flat-file-optional-trailer-plus-optional-delimiter-at-the-end-of-file

Comment: Glad you solved it, these things can send you spinning round in cirlces for days.  where would we be without online peer support?

Comment: Actually, the credit is all yours for putting put me on the right track; by showing me that what I though was the cause of my problem, had nothing to do with it.  And indeed, I have been spinning inside the wheels of FFSW till wee bits of the morning.  Thank God for this site and folks like you!